# Validation summary control not showing message?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with TextBox to enter a Mobile Number.
For that I have validated it using RequiredFieldValidator and RegularExpressionValidator
with display=none:

And also I have placed a ValidationSummary Control

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="mobile" ShowSummary="false" ID="vsValid"
    runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" Enabled="true" 
    DisplayMode="SingleParagraph" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobileNumber" runat="server" CssClass="Qinputbox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtMobileNumber" 
    ID="reqValidMobileNo" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
    ValidationGroup="mobile"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtMobileNumber" Display="None"
    ID="regExValidMobileNo" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid mobile number."
    ValidationExpression="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9]
        (\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$"
    ValidationGroup="mobile"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

when I entered characters in the TextBox it is not showing the summary.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From you code fragment:
`ShowSummary="false"` Looks like a problem.

Comment: hi NetRat,I want to show the message on text change event but not on any post back.I found that validationsummary control will show the message only after a post back is it correct.                                                               I have seen the example at the link  http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/ms/aspdotnet/validationsummary.html

Comment: Pls, check Tim's answer. You want validation w/o postback, then you should set `EnableClientScript="true"`

Answer (score 1):

You should set either `ShowSummary="false"` to `true` or `EnableClientScript="true"`. I'm assuming that you want the latter because you have `ShowMessageBox="true"`.

Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.enableclientscript%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> Use this property to specify whether
>   the ValidationSummary control updates
>   itself using client-side script. When
>   set to true, client-side script is
>   rendered on the client to update the
>   ValidationSummary control, if the
>   browser supports that feature. When
>   set to false, no client-side script is
>   rendered on the client and the
>   ValidationSummary control only updates
>   itself on round-trips to the server.
>   In this situation, the ShowMessageBox
>   property has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In web.config setting:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

This setting turns off Javascript injection of validation (client side).
Remove this and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you do NOT have this in the web.config file:

<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>